# Replying on the same thread of the Twilio number

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I have purchased two numbers from twilio one is for UK and the other one is for US.But when I try to send an SMS to that number from an Indian number.I get the response on a different thread.I want to get a response on the same thread so that my bot and the user have conversation on the same thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I'm afraid that in the Indian market we are currently forced to [work under some restrictions](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223134167-Limitations-sending-SMS-messages-to-Indian-mobile-devices). One of which is:

> 2. The sender IDs are changed to the format “XX-NNNNNN”
>
> The sender IDs are altered before SMS messages are delivered to end
>   users. End users are very likely to see a sender ID composed of 2
>   letters followed by 6 numbers instead of the Sender ID you specified.
>   Due to the sender ID change, SMS recipients are unable to send a reply
>   back to your Twilio phone number.

Unfortunately that means that bot style conversations aren't currently possible in India.